# Google Analytic export data with autometed login

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I wish to develop a php script in order to export some daily data of a Google Analytics account in a separate database through API.
This script must run daily, called with a cron job.

I see that I need to make a manual connect to gather data from google analytics.
Is there a way to automate the login, without doing it manually?

Thanks in advance.
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a service account [Service Account](http://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Also make sure you use the new client lib found here: [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).  The one linked on the service account page is the older version. There should also be some samples in the github project.